Why is chart not shown on page load?
Can someone help me with this one. I have a component where I want to show a chart from ng2-charts/chart.js. I wanted to make it a bit more reactive so therefore I wrote this:
My component:
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { MyService } from './my.service';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-one',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BaseChartDirective, AsyncPipe],
  providers: [MyService],
  template: `
    @if(myDataVM$ | async; as myDataVM) {
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
      <canvas
        baseChart
        [type]="myDataVM.type"
        [options]="myDataVM.options"
        [data]="myDataVM.data"
        [plugins]="myDataVM.plugins"
      ></canvas>
    </div>
    }
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .chart-wrapper {
        display: block;
        height: 85px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class ComponentOneComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input({ required: true }) data!: any;

  myDataVM$ = this.myService.myDataVM$;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['data']) {
      const { currentValue } = changes['data'];
      this.updateChart(currentValue);
    }
  }

  private updateChart(data: any) {
    this.myService.updateChart(data);
  }
}

My Service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartData, ChartType, Plugin } from 'chart.js';
import { combineLatest, map, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private myData$ = new Subject<any>();

  public chartType$: Observable<ChartType> = of('bar');

  public chartOptions$: Observable<ChartConfiguration['options']> = of({
    
    ...

  });

  public chartData$: Observable<ChartData<'bar'>> =
    this.myData$.pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        
        ...

      })
    );

  public chartPlugins$: Observable<Plugin[]> = this.myData$.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      
      ...

    })
  );

  myDataVM$: Observable<any> = combineLatest([
    this.chartType$,
    this.chartOptions$,
    this.chartData$,
    this.chartPlugins$,
  ]).pipe(
    map(([type, options, data, plugins]) => ({
      type,
      options,
      data,
      plugins,
    }))
  );

  constructor() {}

  updateChart(data: any) {
    this.myData$.next(data);
  }
}

I simplified the component and the service for StackOverflow so ignore the any types. In general as you can see I have a service where I want to return a view model from the 4 observables that are in there. Two observables (type and options) have a fixed observable value, but two of them have to react to the changes in the myData$ subject.
This component works just fine if I add another trigger that calls updateChart method or if I use ngAfterViewInit, but I don't think I should use that in this case.
Also I don't know the initial state so therefore I didn't use BehaviorSubject if I did it loads just fine then.
Any suggestions?
Here is a stackblitz project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-naatq6?file=src%2Fmy.service.ts
Ignore that I hardcoded the data. I am mostly interested how can I get line 15 in myService to work instead of line 14.

What is BaseChartDirective? I suspect that's the issue, and doesn't listen to update input values.

It's just a directive that you mast add so you can use ng2-charts inputs on chart element:
https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

Perhaps it would be great that you can reproduce it in the StackBlitz, that it can help us to identify the problem as we don't know what is your Chart configuration and data looks like. Thanks.

Updated the question with link to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-naatq6?file=src%2Fmy.service.ts

If I'm not mistaken, there's nothing but the initial assignment to myData$ which could trigger the onChange, is there? And if not, that may be the simple reason why your chart is not displayed without that initial value.

I provide a data through an input to ComponentOneComponent. ngOnChanges detects this and calls the function which updates the myData Subject in the service. But even though the value is set the chart doesn't show up for some reason

If you don't know the initial value for myData$, you can just provide null.

The Problem

The first (and only) execution of ngOnChanges happens before the component is initialized.
The subscription to myDataVM$ is made with the AsyncPipe after the component is initialized.
The combineLatest operator will not emit until all sources have at least one emissions.  Since myData$ in the service is updated only once, before any subscriptions are made, it will never emit, and therefore the combineLatest used to construct myDataVM$ will also never emit.

Solutions

In the service use a ReplaySubject with a buffer size of 1 when creating myData$.  This way the value is preserved and emitted once a subscription occurs.

private myData$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);


In the component, use toSignal when assigning myDataVM$.  This way the subscription is made immediately.

myDataVM$ = toSignal(this.myService.myDataVM$);

